# taking id and value from a lot of radiobutton by post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In the view I have a lot of `RadioButtons` and the id is the unique for each one. when user choose one of those in controller I would like to take the `ID` and `VALUE` how i can do that.... i try with `formCollection` but in here i just can take value...

```
@Html.RadioButton("BookType", "1", new { id = "100" })
<br>
Above code generates Below code
<br/>
< input id="100" name="BookType" type="radio" value="1" >
```

and the question is how can I take the ID and VALUE by `'POST'` Action in the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code in **Post Action** as follow:

```
var radbtn = Request.From["100"];
```

Comment: in the view i have a lot of RadioButtons and the id is the unique for each one. when user choose one of those in controller i should to take the ID and  VALUE.  PLEASE HELP ME...

Comment: in such situation I create viewModel for my view, and then I can get my viewModel value in post action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, that's not how form controls work.

When you submit a form, the `name` and `value` are submitted, except for scenarios like `checkbox` and `radio` inputs.

Only when a `checkbox` is `checked`, or a `radio input` is `checked` are the `name/value` posted.

You need to re-think what you're trying to achieve. If you can give some more information what you want to achieve I'm sure I or anyone else can help further.

Comment: ok) i want to take the name/value  of many checked-radiobuttons

Comment: @DoszhanBaibatyrov You can't have 'many checked' radio buttons, a radio button is a selection of given options. It sounds like you want to use a checkbox in which case you could specify the value as the Id, and all posted Ids are all the checked checkboxes the user checked.

Comment: yes of course i can choose only one radiobutton if their have the same name but i have some subgroup wich grouped by name  ... thank you,   i found the answer. i used some.getKey(index)-key  some[index]-value/// all good, let me continue to change the life of people of my country ;))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use view model. Please see this example bellow:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers {

    public class TheOption {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool? Checked { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooController : Controller {
        //
        // GET: /Foo/

        public ActionResult Index() {
            var options = new List<TheOption> {
                new TheOption {Id = "One", Value = "The One"},
                new TheOption {Id = "Two", Value = "The Two"},
                new TheOption {Id = "Hundred", Value = "The Hundred"},
            };
            return View(options);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<TheOption> options) {
            return View(options);
        }

    }
}
```

Now you need to create editor template for `TheOption` model. It's simply by create folder named **EditorTemplates** under ~\Views\Shared\ folder. Add new view as the editor template. Name this editor template to match with the model name (`TheOption`).

Here's the content of **~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\TheOption.cshtml**:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.TheOption
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Checked, true, new { id = Model.Id + "_selected" })
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Checked, false, new { id = Model.Id }) @Model.Value

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Value)
</div>
```

Now go to your main view (Index.cshtml) and simply put this code:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication1.Controllers.TheOption>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m)    
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Done! Hope this helps :)